# Should I keep unused img elements in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, performance

I am making a scrollable image gallery, and I'm wondering how I should load my images and whether or not I should remove them from the DOM if the user navigates too far away.

Right now, I have 10 images that are loaded inline with each other, and only one shows in the window. On click and at a set interval, the image scrolls to the next one similar to a slideshow. At the very beginning, I use javascript to append all the `<img src=...>` elements into the DOM.

But, my question is,

1. If there are 1000 images, maybe even more in the gallery, should I still try to load them into my DOM at the start even though only one is shown at a time?
2. Should I remove images from the DOM if they navigate too far away or is it okay to keep in the DOM tree because it has already loaded?

Comment: I think this will solve your problem: **1.** Use image small-size thumbnails to show thumbnails **2.** Use lazyload to load thumbnails **3.** When want to show full-sized image then only load the actual high-scale image

Comment: I feel like the issue there would be that the full-sized image would have a delay on load if it's added only when shown. But I do like that idea, and might modify that to load maybe two or three large images in advance.

Comment: One more improvisation over @Tushar's comment, you can use `nailthumb.js` to scale your images from thumbnail to large image with a  single of image copy.this would improve your performance when working with large no of images. **ref:http://http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php**

Comment: One more thing I forgot to add is to **4.** Cache the images

Comment: @Tushar can you elaborate on that a little? This is a pure javascript application with no server-side caching. Are there client-side optimizations I can do for caching?

Comment: Thanks @dreamweiver I'll definitely take a look into that.

Comment: If you have found your answer,shall we close this question. @tushar could you post your suggestion as answer.

Comment: @dreamweiver No, it better be comments than answer :)